# API category dilemma

Tags: api, categories

just recently discovered stackoverflow and saw what a great site it is. Currently working on a project that verifies the format of an address. honestly speaking I'm still not familiar w/ API/s, so what API/s allows a user to validate an address? just a few examples would do.

and lastly

*Address Validation is in what API category?is it mapping?*

thank you for reading and appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address normalization should fall under the GIS category, for Geographic Information Services.

This task can be performed by gis enabled databases (postgres with postgis and tiger geocoder extension) and implicitly by [google places autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests).

Comment: Provided we are not talking about email address :)

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Mapping sir I asked the question "Address Validation is in what API category?is it mapping?" because of that site and I can't seem to find any GIS category

Comment: Oh well, if you need to define it in terms of that website, I guess it falls under mapping. However, there might be no maps involved in addy normalization. Not until you want to actually display that address.